# Making Backbone.View options mandatory

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am new to Backbone, and I have found myself writing views which rely on values of the `options` object to function properly. In other words, my `options` are mandatory. That doesn't sound right, so I'm wondering if perhaps I'm misusing the `options` parameter, and if so, what's a better way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency injection is a not bad practice at all. It's actually common practice especially dealing with Views. It also makes it easier to unit test your view. So using the `options` to get some required attributes to build your View is completely OK. Maybe a you could share some examples of what you think is wrong?